# CakePHP 3.x: Create a controller object

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to create a list of controller objects

```
use App\Controller\AccessController;

foreach ($controllerlist as $controllerName){
require_once($path); // path for the controller
$clsobj = new $controllerName (); 
$methods = get_class_methods($clsobj);
}
```

In this way I am getting a class not found error

> EX:AccessController not found

but when I hard code the controller name and use it`s work

```
$clsobj = new AccessController (); // this way its work
```

Any Idea how to do ?

Comment: How do you fill this `$controllerlist`?

Comment: I don't think you have to create an instance for each controller. You just can call get_class_methods() using the full path to the controller. i.e. `get_class_methods('\App\Controller\AccessController');`

Comment: Thank for reply @ skywalker  $controllerlist (array of controllers) all the controllers that I have created for project 
@ arilia  get_class_methods('\App\Controller\AccessController') its return a null not returning methods in class :(

Comment: are you sure you set the right namespaces? And are you followeing cake conventions? In fact it should be accessesController. Please post your accessController code

Comment: namespace App\Controller;

    use App\Controller\AppController;
    use Cake\Core\Configure;
    use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
    use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;
    use Cake\Datasource;
    class AccessController extends AppController
    {
    }

***---Acl component that I am creating accessController object --***

namespace Acl\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Utility\Inflector;
use Cake\Filesystem\Folder;
use App\Controller\AccessController;

class AclGenerateComponent extends Component {
}

Comment: I think This is not a naming convention error for the
$clsobj = new AccessController ();  
 use App\Controller\AccessController;  take a used statement but for the 
$clsobj = new $controllerName (); its take as unused statement